# How do I secure and connect to mongodb in a container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to secure a mongoDB docker container and am stumped by the authentication.
So far, in my docker compose file, I am setting root environment variables, but I am unable to connect to the mongoDB from outside of the container. Without setting auth, I have no such issues.

```
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: ["--auth"]
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

I've tried to connect to mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017 using MongoDB Compass tool, but I keep getting authentication errors.

I am assuming that the root user is already created since I am getting authentication errors. I have tried using a script to create a user, but still I could not connect.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 0):

Try without `command: ["--auth"]`

Environment variables that you have provided should already turn this option on. Let me know, if that works.

Comment: Still getting an "Authentication failed" message :(

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was limiting the published ports to the local host. This works fine for my application despite not being able to use set environment variables to get a root user.

```
services: 
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
```